# Capturing pretty-printed string output, to display multiple variables on a single line in gdb?

Tags: formatting, gdb

In my `gdb` session, I have typed this:

```
(gdb) p arg1
$17 = (svn_revnum_t *) 0xbfffea0c
(gdb) p *(arg1)
$18 = -1
```

Now, I would like the "pretty-printed" output for both commands to be shown in a single line, as in:

```
$19 = (svn_revnum_t *) 0xbfffea0c ; -1
```

... so I try something like this:

```
(gdb) p arg1, ";", *(arg1)
$19 = -1
```

... but obviously, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do something like this?

I guess, if it was possible to somehow "capture" the pretty-printed output of `print` as a string, then I could use `printf "%s ; %s"` to format my output; but how would one capture the `print` output, then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to write a new Python command that does what you want.

Alternatively you could write a Python convenience function that uses str on its argument.  Then, use that with printf.